# Is it possible to generate serializable classes with CXF?

Tags: java, serialization, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF to generate classes from a WSDL file but they don't implement Serializable which is needed to put an object into a JMS queue. Is it possible to do this or do I have to convert the generated classes into my own and send those?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution myself so here it is if anybody needs it in the future:

**`1. add this plugin to pom.xml`**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources</wsdlRoot>
                <includes>
                    <include>*Service.wsdl</include>
                </includes>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/your_wsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-server</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**`2. write a custom binding (binding.xml)`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="Send.wsdl"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <jaxws:bindings
        node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://wsdl/SendService.wsdl']">
        <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <jxb:serializable uid="11082011"/>
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

**`3. run 'mvn generate-sources'`**

Comment: Note that you need to make a couple of changes to your binding.xml file. 1. Swap out `Send.wsdl` in line 2 to whatever your WSDL is named, and 2. Replace the `node` attribute in line 8 with whatever your target namespace is, as suggested [here](http://markmail.org/message/aw52wgp6bdpwo5rx)

Answer (score 5):

Binding files with <jaxws:bindings> root element work with jaxb:globalBindings only if your wsdl has a single schema. The problem is that jaxb:globalBindings is global so it can not be specified more than once.

If that is your case you can use the following bindings file with jaxb:bindings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simpler version of **bindings.xml**, which make sure that all generated files are implementing Serializable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings>
                <xjc:serializable />
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:schema>
```