# Camel Multicast; Direct and AMQ

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a Generic Camel Route which listens to a CXF:Bean(SOAP) Request with DataFormat: POJO.

What I want this route to do is multicast the incoming exchange to AMQ JMS Queue, which will be consumed by another internal route at a later point and the other endpoint is a direct:Endpoint which will be utilised to reply with SOAP Message saying i.e. "Success"

However, I get the following error with StackTrace:

```
015-06-03 16:56:49.645  INFO 4992 --- [qtp110495750-79] XxToYyyAsynchronizerRoute                : An error has occurred. java.lang.RuntimeException: xxx.zzz.yyy.xx_to_zzz.RequestType
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.storeContent(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:118)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.setObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:169)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessageForType(JmsBinding.java:561)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:473)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.makeJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:289)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer$2.createMessage(JmsProducer.java:297)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:274)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:217)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$1.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:231)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:493)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:228)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:431)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:385)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:153)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:95)
at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My route is define as per below:

```
        onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "An error has occurred. ${exception.stacktrace}");

    from("{{xyz.route.zzz.soap.endpoint}}")
        .routeId(xx_TO_zz_ROUTE_ID)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Placing messages into generic queue!")
        .multicast().parallelProcessing().to("{{xxx.yy.to.zzz.jms.queue}}", "{{aaaa.xxx.generic.route}}");
}
```

For testing purposes if I remove the QueueEndpoint and only send it to the GenericRoute I get a the SOAP Response with "SUCCESS". I am suspicious that I am not using the multicast properly or that AMQ(JMS) Queue doesn't work with POJO data format?

Can anyone help please? :|

Comment: Is your POJO serializable? You can send a POJO through JMS, using an ObjectMessage as the JMS message (which Camel will do for you), but it must implement Serializable (Active MQ actually does allow non-serializable java object as messages, but only if you use VM transport and if you set an option to disable object serialization).

Comment: So if one of your endpoints works, what about the other one? You can remove the multicast and simply send it to a JMS queue and see if it goes through. As previous commenter mentioned, it could as well be that your POJO is not serialisable.

Comment: Hi, no the POJO's are not Serialiazable. They're auto-generated using wsdl2java tool. Is there a work around it to make it work with non-serialiazable POJO's. I'm using an embeddedAMQ which uses VM transportation btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I took the lead from Cyaegha (Thank you) and I generated POJO's using wsdl2java using the answer below.

[Solution for wsdl2java serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009586/is-it-possible-to-generate-serializable-classes-with-cxf)

Using these POJO's which implement Serializable interface now works!

Happy times! =)